# Gesture detector on tap not working in flutter release app but working in debug app

Tags: flutter

I am using firestore and created 4 cards on which the user taps on goes to the next screen. Everything is working fine in debug mode, in debug mode both **Inkwell** and **Gesture Detector** are working but when I make a release version I don't know why but both **Inkwell** and **Gesture Detector** are not working. Have no idea what's causing this. Please help.

```
    class _RestaurantDashboardState extends State<RestaurantDashboard> {

  Widget buildRestaurantCards(String title, IconData iconData, int orderCount) {
    return Expanded(
      child: GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
        onTap: () {
          if (title == "Menu\nManagement") {
            Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MenuManagement()));
          } else if (title == "Current Orders") {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => OrderScreen("In Progress"),
              ),
            );
          } else if (title == "Order History") {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => OrderHistory("In Progress"),
              ),
            );
          } else if (title == "Update Profile") {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) =>
                    RestaurantSignUp(Utils.restaurant!.restaurantId, true),
              ),
            );
          }
        },
        child: Container(
          height: double.infinity,
          child: Card(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              elevation: 8,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        orderCount > 0
                            ? Row(
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                    width: 30,
                                    height: 30,
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                                    child: FittedBox(
                                        child: Text(
                                      orderCount.toString(),
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                                    )),
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.red,
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              )
                            : SizedBox(),
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                          child: Icon(
                            iconData,
                            size: 40,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      margin:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 16),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: FittedBox(
                        child: Text(
                          title,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      )),
                ],
              )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Dashboard'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: [
                    isFirebaseInitialized
                        ? StreamBuilder(
                            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                .collection("orders")
                                .snapshots(),
                            builder: (context,
                                AsyncSnapshot<
                                        QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>
                                    snapshot) {
                              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                                setState(() {
                                  _isLoading = false;
                                });
                                return Container();
                              }

                              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                setState(() {
                                  _isLoading = false;
                                });
                              }

                              List<DocumentSnapshot> itemsList = [];
                              for (DocumentSnapshot doc
                                  in snapshot.data!.docs) {
                                if (doc['restaurantId'] ==
                                        Utils.restaurant!.restaurantId &&
                                    doc['orderStatus'] == "In Progress") {
                                  itemsList.add(doc);
                                }
                              }

                              return buildRestaurantCards("Current Orders",
                                  Icons.list_alt, itemsList.length);
                            },
                          )
                        : buildRestaurantCards(
                            "Current Orders", Icons.list_alt, 0),
                    buildRestaurantCards("Order History", Icons.history, 0),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: [
                    buildRestaurantCards(
                        "Menu\nManagement", Icons.restaurant_menu_rounded, 0),
                    buildRestaurantCards("Update Profile", Icons.person, 0),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )


        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Are there any exceptions caught in the debug console?

Comment: Yes, there were some warnings for overflowing widgets, solving which solved my error. Thanks

Comment: No problem, happy to help

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if there are any exceptions caught in the debug console, If there are then fix those, then the issue will be resolved